# Create new directory kdb+

Tags: kdb

I am learning how to use kdb at the moment. 
My question is how do I create a new directory inside the directory that I start q from. 
This is to resolve the problem of not having enough RAM to store large financial data sets.

Comment: Are you sure you mean RAM and not ROM? Creating a new directory won't help with not having enough RAM for your q process.

Comment: How large and what format is the dataset? are you definitely getting the `wsfull` error when loading it in?

Comment: What are the contents of this starting directory? Is the q instance automatically loading in large flat files?

Answer (score 4):

One way of getting around the problem of not having enough memory is writing your data sets to disk as partitioned tables, and then mapping them back into memory. This will allow you to query them whilst only loading the relevant columns and partitions into memory.

If you're feeling relatively comfortable with q you could read [this](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/) chapter from the book *Q for Mortals*, which explains how to work with large datasets.